# Creating markers on google Map

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps

I am trying to add multiple google markers on a map and I am not sure why this code does not work. I am using php and javascript. I checked to see if `$DNB` had elements and it did. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
                        while($DNB -> fetch())
                            {
                                ?>
                                 var point  = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo initval( $lat)?>, <?php echo initval($lon)?>);
                                 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: point, map:map});
                             <?php }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
var point=  new GLatLng(<?php echo intval($lat) ?>],<?php echo intval($lon)?>);
```

is Google Maps API V2. This code:

```
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: point, map:map});
```

Is Google Maps API V3. Pick one, and I strongly suggest V3. Check out the documentation at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/

Comment: I have changed GLatLng to GLatLong and I still get no markers.

Comment: var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title:"Hello World!"
  });

Comment: Please consult this documentation:https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Markers

Comment: I have everything posted above. I also ran a new php file to make sure I stored the latitudes and longitudes. Maybe its a php issue?

Comment: Can you post a version of it live so that we can at least check out the javascript? And what you've done with GLatLng isn't Google Maps API V3, it's new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude);

Comment: Is there something wrong with my DNB query? Does the ? character have a problem?